# my serializeUser isn't being called during LocalStrategy done callback

Tags: javascript, passport.js

My problem is that I'm getting the error "Error: Failed to serialize user into session". I'm confused, because I've set a serializeUser function, but it doesn't appear to be called (my console.log isn't being printed).

This is while I'm following the feathers passport tutorial: http://feathersjs.com/learn/authorization/

Note: my suspicion is that feathers-passport uses a different "passport" object than my own library. Unfortunately I have no idea how I would rememdy such an issue. It seems to me it's just horrendous design by Passport to not work by passing around instances, and instead attaching things to itsself directly.

I'm setting up passport for serialization and authentication using the following:

```
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

function GetPassport(userService, Passport) {
    console.log('passport has been prepared.\n');
    Passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        console.log('user: ', user);
        done(null, user._id);
    });

    Passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        userService.get(id, {}, done);
    });

    Passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {
        userService.authenticate(username, password, done);
    }));

    return Passport;
}

module.exports = GetPassport;
```

Then I'm using:

```
var userService = UserService(config.db);
var passport = GetPassport(userService);
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'));
```

---

If you need more details here is UserService:

```
var MongoDB = require('feathers-mongodb');
var Crypto = require('crypto');

var UserService = function(database) {
    return MongoDB({
        db: database,
        collection: '_users',
    }).extend({
        authenticate: function(username, password, callback) {
            this.find({query: {username: username}}, function(error, users) {
                if(error)
                    callback(error);

                var user = users[0];
                if(!user)
                    return callback(new Error('No User Found'));

                if(user.password !== hash(password, user.salt))
                    return callback(new Error('Password Is Incorrect'));

                //success, return the authenticated user
                return callback(null, user);
            });
        },
        setup: function() {
            this.before({
                create: function(hook, next) {
                    //Create the salt
                    var salt = Crypto.randomBytes(128).toString('base64');
                    hook.data.salt = salt;
                    hook.data.password = hash(hook.data.password, hook.data.salt);

                    next();
                },
            });
        },
    });
};

module.exports = UserService;

function hash(string, salt) {
    var shasum = Crypto.createHash('sha256');
    shasum.update(string + salt);
    return shasum.digest('hex');
}
```

The error trace:

```
Error: Failed to serialize user into session
    at pass (/Users/funk/Development/Projects/generic_rest_server/node_modules/feathers-passport/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:277:19)
    at Authenticator.serializeUser (/Users/funk/Development/Projects/generic_rest_server/node_modules/feathers-passport/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:295:5)
    at IncomingMessage.req.login.req.logIn (/Users/funk/Development/Projects/generic_rest_server/node_modules/passport/lib/http/request.js:48:29)
    at Strategy.strategy.success (/Users/funk/Development/Projects/generic_rest_server/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:228:13)
    at verified (/Users/funk/Development/Projects/generic_rest_server/node_modules/passport-local/lib/strategy.js:83:10)
    at /Users/funk/Development/Projects/generic_rest_server/user-service.js:22:24
    at /Users/funk/Development/Projects/generic_rest_server/node_modules/feathers-mongodb/node_modules/mongoskin/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:158:16
    at commandHandler (/Users/funk/Development/Projects/generic_rest_server/node_modules/feathers-mongodb/node_modules/mongoskin/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:651:16)
    at /Users/funk/Development/Projects/generic_rest_server/node_modules/feathers-mongodb/node_modules/mongoskin/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1670:9
    at Server.Base._callHandler (/Users/funk/Development/Projects/generic_rest_server/node_modules/feathers-mongodb/node_modules/mongoskin/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:382:41)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was in my note.

This should be helpful for anyone else who gets stuck following:
"http://feathersjs.com/learn/authorization/"

You must provide the FeathersPassport call with the passport option. If not, feathers-passport well use a different version of passport, than the one you add serializeUser to:

```
   app.configure(FeathersPassport(function(result) {
        // MongoStore needs the session function
        var MongoStore = ConnectMongo(result.createSession);

        result.secret = 'noymysecret';
        result.store = new MongoStore({
            db: config.db,
        });
        result.resave = false;
        result.saveUninitialized = false;

        //*HERE*//
        result.passport = passport;
        //**//

        return result;
    }));
```

I blame Passport inexplicably being a singleton, for not noticing this sooner.